# Removing objects from lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure why I get an error saying index out of range when I test this function. Can anyone please help me fix this?

```
def intersect_lists(L1, L2):
'''(list, list) -> list
Return L1 with items not in L2 removed.
>>> intersect_lists([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 2, 6])
[2,4,6]
'''
new_list = []

for item in range(len(L1)):
    if L1[item] == L2[item]:
        new_list.append(L1[item])
return new_list
```

Comment: Show the full error message.

Comment: you use "len(L1)" as range-parameter. You have to substract 1 from that. An array starts at index 0, so [1,2] has the indexes 0 and 1, but the length will be 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
def intersect_lists(L1, L2):
   return [i for i in L1 if i in L2]
```

However, your specific error is being caused by the fact that you are iterating over the length of L1, which will ultimately lead to an index error because the length of L1 is greater than L2.

Without list comprehension:

```
def intersect_lists(L1, L2):
   final_list = []
   for i in L1:
      if i in L2:
         final_list.append(i)

   return final_list
```

Comment: How can I do it without list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

Or Boolean And:

```
list(set(L1) & set(L2))
```